# Does loop processing depend on echo statements when it iterates for large number of index values?

Tags: php, loops, large-data

I've been working with 2 nested loops in PHP where the outer loop is executing over an array that has around 25K records and there is some processing that is being done in the inner loop for an array that has around 3000 records again.

The strange issue that I've found is when I use an echo statement in the outer loop, the script is terminating with expected result but without the echo statement, it keeps on processing and terminates after around 3 minutes without any result.

What can be the issue here?

Sample pseudo code:

```
for ($index = 0 ; $index <= 25,000 ; $index++)
{
  for($indx = 0 ;  $indx <= 3,000 ; $indx++)
  {
    //process logic
  }
echo "Test Flow";   //with this, it works. Without it, enters infinite loop
}
```

Comment: Do you have `break;, continue;` inside your loops?

Comment: `$indx`? Maybe your forgot to set `$indx++` in inner loop?

Comment: @masterFly Yes I'm using break & continue statements to establish a certain logic. Is it causing some issue? But if yes, then how is it working perfectly with the echo statement?

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks. Had missed out adding the increment here. In the actual code it's there.

Comment: May be you should check on those statements. I dont see much problem in this code. Basically if you run what you have pasted here, Do you get the same error? no right?

Comment: @masterFly Yeah I agree. It shouldn't cause any issue ideally when implemented separately

Comment: @VinodKirte, So its not the loops. Probably some where on your logic!

Comment: @masterFly Ok. Let's say that the logic has issues but then can you explain why a single echo statement changes the scenario and it works perfectly?

Comment: @VinodKirte, explanation depends, Since `break` and `continue` can be in inner loop. Are you sure those statements produce exactly what you need? If it is the `loop` and the `echo` statement it could be reproduced with the code that you have pasted here right?

Comment: Another could happend triggers when reading @RyanVincent comment. Check where you have same variable names which you use in both inner and out loops

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for the comment but I've tried all the 3 things that you mentioned 1) I've tested it for smaller loops and it is working perfectly for both with & without the echo statement 2) To test the infinite loop condition, I had given the "Test Flow" echo in outer loop, with which it works fine. 3) In the actual code, I've followed standard name conventions

Comment: @masterFly Yes. I've tested the logic and the positioning of "break" / "continue" statements which seems to be fine as you can see in my previous comments that it's working perfectly with smaller loops and with the echo statement. So I'm really puzzled. PS: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @RyanVincent Okay. Thanks. I'll try log instead of echo to see what's happening. I've tried error_reporting(E_ALL); but that didn't report anything as the file's execution stops abruptly after 3 minutes

Comment: You meeting the PHP execution timeout limit? If so increase it or set it to zero. try: wrap the whole outer loop in a try .. catch for now - just report the exception and die if you get one. Please don't leave the try .. catch in after you have debugged this.

Comment: @RyanVincent I've already set the time limit to zero. I'll do the try catch thing as well. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanVincent Correction: The file doesn't stop executing but I guess it enters an infinite processing loop as the output is blank. I've already set the time limit to zero but as the iterations are large, I can't see results in limited time. I'll do the try catch thing as well. Thanks.